# Adaptar diseño web a todas las pantallas (HTML, CSS, JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

=)

Hay alguna manera de adaptar una página web a a cualquier pantalla?

Acabo de acabar mi diseño principal y siempre he trabajado sobre la misma pantalla para ver como iba quedando, y cuando he acabado, y cambio a otra pantalla, hay cosas que se me descentran. Y claro, en una queda bien, pero en la otra se descentra. Adjunto codigo html y css de lo que se me descentra. Un saludo! =)

HTML (Primera Parte):

```
<section class="about-us">
    <div class="contenedor1">
        <h2 class="titulo" style="color:#fff" align="center">We provide all that you need</h2>
        <div class="contenedor-articulo">
            <div class="articulo">
                <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>
                <h3 style="color:#00ff00" align="center">3 different files</h3>
                <p style="color:white" align="center">Lorem Ipsum jasdasdkasdahaofabs jasdojasdad sdoafbasf jbkfbaksf a f bjafkabfka fa f asfbna kfjkbsjfbasf.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="articulo">
                <i class="fas fa-crosshairs"></i>
                <h3 style="color:#00ff00" align="center">Mixed Combos</h3>
                <p style="color:white" align="center">Lorem Ipsum jasdasdkasdahaofabs jasdojasdad sdoafbasf jbkfbaksf a f bjafkabfka fa f asfbna kfjkbsjfbasf.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="articulo">
                <i class="fas fa-wallet"></i>
                <h3 style="color:#00ff00" align="center">Cheap Price</h3>
                <p style="color:white" align="center">Lorem Ipsum jasdasdkasdahaofabs jasdojasdad sdoafbasf jbkfbaksf a f bjafkabfka fa f asfbna kfjkbsjfbasf.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="articulo">
                <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                <h3 style="color:#00ff00" align="center">Private Sources</h3>
                <p style="color:white" align="center">Lorem Ipsum jasdasdkasdahaofabs jasdojasdad sdoafbasf jbkfbaksf a f bjafkabfka fa f asfbna kfjkbsjfbasf.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="articulo">
                <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                <h3 style="color:#00ff00" align="center">Combos Checked</h3>
                <p style="color:white" align="center">Lorem Ipsum jasdasdkasdahaofabs jasdojasdad sdoafbasf jbkfbaksf a f bjafkabfka fa f asfbna kfjkbsjfbasf.</p>  
            </div>
            <div class="articulo">
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <h3 style="color:#00ff00" align="center">Quality Guaranteed</h3>
                <p style="color:white" align="center">Lorem Ipsum jasdasdkasdahaofabs jasdojasdad sdoafbasf jbkfbaksf a f bjafkabfka fa f asfbna kfjkbsjfbasf.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS (Primera Parte):

```
.about-us{
    background: #000000;
}

.contenedor-articulo{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 60px;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.articulo{
    width: 29%;
    background: #000000;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 45px 30px 60px 30px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.articulo:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(17, 29, 48, .26);
}

.articulo>i{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #1FDE82;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 32px rgba(31, 222, 130, .46);
    margin-left: 120px;
}

.articulo>h3{
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.articulo>p{
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #5d6678;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.articulo>a{
    color: #5d6678;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.articulo>a:hover{
    color: #1FDE82;
    transition: color .5s;
}
```

HTML (Segunda Parte)

```
<section class="questions">
            <section class="textos-questions">
                <h1>Our objective is your success</h1>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum jasdasdkasdahaofabs jasdojasdad sdoafbasf jbkfbaksf a f bjafkabfka fa f asfbna kfjkbsjfbasf.</p>
                <a href="#" style="color:black"><b>Learn More</b></a>
            </section>
            <img src="img/interview.svg">
    </section>
```

CSS (Segunda Parte):

```
.questions {
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background: #000000;
}

.questions>img {
    width: 550px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

.textos-questions {
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}

.textos-questions p {
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-top: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}

.textos-questions h1{
    color: #00ff00;
}

.textos-questions a {
    margin: 28px 0 0 0;
    width: 130px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #00ff00;
    text-align: center;
    color: #00ff00;
    padding: 12px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 32px rgba(31, 222, 130, .46);
}
```

HTML (Tercera Parte):

```
<section class="services">
    <img src="img/hero-banner.png" alt="">
    <div class="box-skills">
        <h4><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> Efficiency</h4>
        <h4><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> 24/7 Support</h4>
        <h4><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> High Quality Service</h4>
        <h4><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> PayPal Allowed</h4>
        <div class="cross">
            <h4><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>Reselling is not allowed</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS (Tercera Parte):

```
.services {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: #000000;
    padding-top: 120px;
}

.services>img {
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.box-skills {
    margin: 30px 100px 0 0;
}

.box-skills h4 {
    width: 350px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 30px;

}

.box-skills i {
    color: #1FDE82;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 32px rgba(31, 222, 130, .46);
}

.cross i{
    color: #ff3300;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-right:11px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

En una parte queda centrado, y en la otra se desplaza.
Adjunto fotos también de ambos resultados, por si es de ayuda =).

Muchisimas gracias! He intentado de todo, pero no lo consigo.

Dejo enlace de descarga de un archivo .rar con las correspondientes fotos, por si ayuda a describir el problema que tengo. =)

Un saludo! Y gracias! =)

https://mega.nz/file/VPw2hCRQ#cNTodoijZMoz2taKFKgYrFjv9ivg-HltlsEcYhyAZtk

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer una pagina web responsive puedes hacer uso de los llamados `media querys` del lado de `CSS`, para poder usar media querys deberás de usar una etiqueta `meta`, en este caso yo le llamo `meta viewport`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Esta iria dentro de las etiquetas head de tu código, y te permite hacer uso de media querys.

Lo siguiente es como declarar un media query en `CSS`, para declarar un media query en `CSS` existen multiples formas y atributos que se les puede dar, pero en general los media query van al final del documento `CSS`, un ejemplo de un media query es usar la medida `max-width` para poder realizar algún cambio a los elementos de una pagina web cuando la pagina alcance cierto ancho maximo.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que queremos hacerle cambios a un elemento html que nosotros tengamos y que se vea diferente cuando alcance una medida de por ejemplo `600px` o menos, entonces el mediaquery para esto se vería así:

```css
h1{
  /*
    Estilos normales del h1 para cuando no se haya alcanzado
    la medida por el media query.
  */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){

  /*
    Aquí dentro todo lo que alcanze menos o igual a 600px
    de ancho en la pantalla será ejecutado (los estilos).
  */
  h1{
    color: red;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>Hola mundo</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Para poder que puedas ver este media query en funcionamiento deberás de ampliar el snippet e ir cambiandole el tamaño al ancho de tu ventana hasta que te encuentres en una medida de 600px o menor.

También es importante decir que puedes tener diferentes media querys en tu `CSS` con diferentes medidas, entonces para hacer que un elemento se adapte al tamaño de la pantalla de la persona, bastara con usar medidas en porcentajes.

Por ejemplo, podemos hacer que una imagen que no usa porcentajes en sus medidas repentinamente al entrar en un ancho de pantalla de 700px use siempre el ancho completo de la pantalla:

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img{
  /*
    Ancho fijo de la imagen.
  */
  width: 500px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){

  /*
    Aquí dentro todo lo que alcanze menos o igual a 600px
    de ancho en la pantalla será ejecutado (los estilos).
  */
  img{
    width: 100%
  }
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    
    <img src = "https://img.freepik.com/foto-gratis/fondo-negro-vacio-luz-iluminada-ademas_93675-45849.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg">

</body>
</html>
```

Para poder ver el trabajo en accion de este media query, ampliar el snippet y reducir el ancho de la ventana a 700px o menos, en un inicio la imagen siempre abarca 500px de ancho, pero jamas el ancho de la ventana y cuando entramos a los 700px delimitados del media query la imagen pasa a abarcar siempre el 100% del tamaño de la pantalla, así entonces es como podemos hacer sitios web responsive, muy sencillo, facil de implementar y entender.

Solo debes recordar que para poder usar media querys debes usar esta etiqueta `meta`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

De lo contrario no veras cambio alguno al hacer escalados de pantalla.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! =)

Comment: De nada amigo, para servirte, recuerda que si te fue de ayuda mi respuesta, puedes darla como aceptada dandole al boton que parece un chulo.

Answer (score -1):

Agrega "text-align: center;" a la clase '.articulo' y no en '.articulo>i'

```
        .articulo{
            width: 29%;
            background: #000000;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 45px 30px 60px 30px;
            transition: 0.5s;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

También elimina el el margin-left a la clase '.articulo>i'

```
        .articulo>i{
            font-size: 30px;
            color: #fff;
            background: #1FDE82;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 70px;
            height: 70px;
            padding-top: 20px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            box-shadow: 0 8px 32px rgba(31, 222, 130, .46);
        }
```

Eso debería resolver el problema

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! =)